# PDF with javascript "print()" inside. Missing font

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, printing

**Reason why I am writing a question**
I was looking for a solution, where I can force print dialog for PDF file, which could work through all browsers. The thing is, I had hard time using JavaScript to print an iframe in Firefox. So I found some information, that I can put javascript into the PDF file.

**What have I tried you may ask...**
According to this article:
http://bililite.com/blog/2012/06/06/adding-javascript-to-pdf-files/

I managed to add `app.alert('Hello, World!')` to the file, which actually pops up the alert. Tweaked a bit, changed it to print() and it works like a charm.
I am loading PDF into the iframe (0 width / 0 height) and I get the print dialog. The only problem is, if I print it using chrome or IE, I get everything right, but if I print using firefox, i get small squares instead of letters. Is it possible there is something wrong with font?

I can provide the example PDF with javascript in the file. Print dialog also pops up if I open it in windows.

**The code I've put into file**

```
<< /JavaScript 
  << /Names 
     [(EmbeddedJS)
      << 
       /S /JavaScript /JS (print();)
      >>
     ] 
  >>
>>
```

If I press CANCEL, the PDF in iframe looks alright, and if I pick print then, it will print it properly. Is it possible that javascript is trying to print it too soon? That fonts aren't loaded yet?